# How to call this webservice: http://www.grubolympx.com/app/rating.php in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, http

Whenever I call the webservice: http://www.grubolympx.com/app/rating.php, it sends "Please send appropriate value" message.

Please give the idea to pass appropriate value to this webservice for retrieving data.

This is my code:

```
public String readFeed() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vogella.json");
    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://ragecomics.cloudapp.net/RestService.svc/json/Hot/0");

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.grubolympx.com/app/rating.php?q=India");
    httpGet.setHeader("content-type", "application/php");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {

             HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(AdcActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

## iPhone code:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"grubolympx.com/app/rating.php"]; 
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
  [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"]; 
  [request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"]; 
  [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"]; 
  [request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
  [request setDelegate:self]; 
  [request startAsynchronous]; } 
–

(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request { 
  NSString *responseString = [request responseString]; 
  NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue]; 
  NSLog(@"%@",responseString); 
  if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) { 
    // Display succeed msg 
    [Appirater appLaunched]; 
  } else{ NSLog(@"%@",responseString); } 
– 

else if (responseDict != NULL){ 
  NSMutableDictionary *rateDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease]; 
  [rateDictionary setObject:[responseDict valueForKey:@"dishes"] forKey:@"Foodname"];
  [rateDictionary setObject:[responseDict valueForKey:@"ratings"] forKey:@"rating"];
  [rateDictionary setObject:[responseDict valueForKey:@"country"] forKey:@"country"];
  [self updateAverageRateWith:rateDictionary]; 
  // Update average rate in rateArray. 
}
```

Comment: Have you given permission in your menifest file to use internet like this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

Comment: Problem is not in your code. If you access the link you gave it will give you the same response. Maybe you need authentification or your url is wrong.

Comment: i have give permission for internet in manifest

Comment: is there any to pass parameter while calling activity.

Comment: this webservice is already called in iphone in which it working fine. in iphone it also take take dictionary. how can be it in android. iphone code is like this

Comment: can some give similar code like iphone

Comment: What's the JSON string that's only present in the iPhone version look like? You don't seem to have an equivalent in your 'droid version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It responds with the same message when you paste that URL into a web browser.

If you run their app while connected to your PC does log cat show anything useful?

Comment: in order to send value to server you should use httppost method by the way. getting same response from a web browser is an obvious thing, since you get from builder.toString() the same response..

Comment: Open http://www.grubolympx.com/app/rating.php?q=India in your browser. You don't necessarily need to send as HTTP POST, but you definitely need to need to ask grubolympx for the correct query string, with examples and confirm that GET is supported (get makes more sense than post because query string is short and does not change the state of anything on the server)

Comment: Can you provide the iPhone source? The answer is probably in the extra fields provided by the dictionary. Also provide the log output from when you run the iPhone app

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.grubolympx.com/app/rating.php"];
    
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [request  setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    
    [request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"]; 
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request appendPostData:[jsonString  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    
}

Comment: (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
       
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    
    if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) {
        
       // Display succeed msg
        [Appirater appLaunched];
        
    }
    else{
        
        NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
        
    }

Comment: else if (responseDict != NULL){
        
        NSMutableDictionary *rateDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [rateDictionary setObject:[responseDict valueForKey:@"dishes"] forKey:@"Foodname"];
        [rateDictionary setObject:[responseDict valueForKey:@"ratings"] forKey:@"rating"]; 
        [rateDictionary setObject:[responseDict valueForKey:@"country"] forKey:@"country"];
        
        [self updateAverageRateWith:rateDictionary];  // Update average rate in rateArray.
        
    }

Comment: You need to do a HTTP POST with the JSON data attached as the iPhone app does.   Where does "jsonString" come from?

Comment: can u give some thing similar in android

Comment: @denizt has provided an example HttpPost request.  You need to figure out how your iPhone app creates "jsonString"

Comment: i dont know how to make json string in android

Comment: I don't think you're building a very complex json structure.  "{\"param1\":\"" + value1 + "\", \"param2\":\"" + value2 + "\"}"

Comment: i just have three param i.e country= countryName, food = foodname and rating is to retrive on the basis of first two params

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with JSON? It's pretty simple. Visit http://json.org otherwise install and use the Poster Firefox plugin to get an idea of what the requests need to look like.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i understood from your question, you are trying to send data to a php file on a server in order to retrieve response. So you have to use Http post method to do that. Try following code in order to send a value to server:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); // url = webpage u send data with request
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params)); //params is a List<NameValuePair> where you store your value to send server

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent(); //is is an InputStream
```

and to retrieve response use following code piece:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
json = sb.toString();
Log.e("json", json);
```

After that point you can parse json you retrieve from server and gather data.

Comment: its not work for me. when i pass another webservice it work but my webservice dose not work

Comment: you have to give correct value pair in order to get a response from server. my guess is you are posting data with incorrect value pair.

Comment: how can we pass dictinoary with url like iphone

Comment: String foodname = foodtitle.getText().toString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("rating","");
    jsonObject.put("dish",foodname);
    jsonObject.put("country",name);JSONArray jArrayParam = new JSONArray();jArrayParam.put(jsonObject);List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mydata",jArrayParam.toString()));HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.grubolympx.com/app/rating.php");
   httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "httppost");

Comment: httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8));
   
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the service is working from the person who has developed it..and also ask him for the parameters to be passed to get the right response..

Comment: the above url working in iphone but not in androiad . so url is correct ,i think my mistake in my code .So plz help me , i will respect to all ideas.